# Is java.text.DecimalFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits() being ignored?

Tags: java, validation

I've been trying to use `java.text.DecimalFormat` to validate user input of decimal numbers.  I know the maximum number of digits both before and after the decimal place that are to be allowed - if there are more of either, that's an input error by the user.  It seems like `setMaximumIntegerDigits()` is not being enforced though.  (Or if I use a pattern, rather than the min/max setters, the maximum digits implied by the pattern seem again to be ignored.)

What am I missing?

(Apologies if this is a duplicate.  I can find a lot of questions about `DecimalFormat` on SO - but none that seem to be quite this problem.)

Here's the sample code and a unit test (distilled from real code):

---- Numbers.java

```
/** Utility for creating and using a standard DecimalFormat. */ 
package com.myco.util;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

public final class Numbers {

    private Numbers() { ; }

    public static DecimalFormat standardFormat() {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);
        df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        return df;
    }

    // Alternatively, approach, also doesn't work.
    /*public static DecimalFormat standardFormat() {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0.##");
        df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        return df;
    }*/

    public static BigDecimal match(DecimalFormat df, String s)
    throws NumberFormatException {
        if(s == null || (s = s.trim()).length() == 0)
            return null;
        ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
        Number n = df.parse(s, pp);
        if(n == null || pp.getIndex() != s.length())
            throw new NumberFormatException(
                "Invalid BigDecimal for format '"+df+"'!");
        return BigDecimal.class.cast(n);
    }

}
```

By my reading of the Javadoc for `DecimalFormat` the test for 1000 (below) should pass
(that is, it should throw an exception) but it doesn't.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

---- Numbers_Test.java

```
package com.myco.util;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public final class Numbers_Test extends TestCase {

    public void testOkay() {
        DecimalFormat df = Numbers.standardFormat();
        assertEquals("0.1", Numbers.match(df, "0.1").toString());
        assertEquals("4.2", Numbers.match(df, "4.2").toString());
        assertEquals("999.99", Numbers.match(df, "999.99").toString());
    }

    public void testFail() {
        DecimalFormat df = Numbers.standardFormat();
        try {
            // Returns 1000 (as BigDecimal) but should fail (?).
            Numbers.match(df, "1000");
            fail();
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) { ; }
    }

}
```

Comment: `DecimalFormat` and `NumberFormat` javadocs for `set(Maximum|Minimum)(Integer|Fraction)Digits` methods mention that these properties are used when "formatting" or "showing" numbers. There is not a word that these properties are used when parsing. This is pretty vague but in the end these properties indeed are used only for formatting.

Comment: I did wonder if that might be the case.  But it also doesn't work with a pattern (for example, ##0.## as shown above in the alternative, commented out code).  Surely a pattern ought to be being applied for parsing too?

Comment: Simple answer: yes, it has no effect at all. For formatting, cutting the number of digits would produce a wrong number and, yes, it ought to parse the same values it produces by formatting. You might implement your own `Format` classes doing something with these properties…

Comment: So how can you - or even can you - use `DecimalFormat` for simple input format validation?  I'm pretty sure you can because (a long, long time ago) I seem to remember doing so in conjunction with `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: You can use it for validating that the input is a valid number. You can not use it to set an implied maximum via number-of-digits. For doing what you want to do with `JFormattedTextField` you may have a look at [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html)…

Comment: @Holger I don't want to 'cut' (i.e. drop, discard) any digits.  I just want their presence to be a formatting error.  Which, according to the docs for the `parse()` method should mean returning null (and setting an error index on the `ParsePosition`) if the pattern is not matched.

Comment: @Holger `MaskFormatter` looks interesting, I'll read up...

Comment: But you know that a `DecimalFormat` can *format* a value as well? What do you expect when you would set the maximum number of digits to `3` and tell it to format the value `1234567`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything - I'm *not* going to use it to format at all.  But... if it doesn't get applied when parsing, and (by your implication) it is ignored for formatting (to avoid chopping the high-end off the number) what, then, is `setMaximumIntegerDigits()` any good for?